# How to remove the gradient from dash lenses?

Tags: unity-dash

[image]

In every lens of the dash in 15.04 (and previous releases) there seems to be a gradient at the top right of every row. Is there an easy way I could remove this gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit it with GIMP or other image editors, because the `.png` files are stored in

```
/usr/share/unity/icons
```

The name of the files are `category_gradient.png` and  `category_gradient_no_refine.png`.

Comment: Twice the same image?

Comment: sorry filename didn't copied and i pasted previous one.

Comment: @AndreyOrst, thanks, that worked! You'll also have to restart Unity for the changes to apply. Either restart Ubuntu or do the following:

1. Press ALT+F2
2. Type "unity" in the dash and press ENTER